# Issue with my script to store Google spreadsheet data daily

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been having trouble getting my scripts to work for my investment portfolio spreadsheet. They were working fine until early May and I've been unable to get them to work since. What I'm trying to do is store the performance of my portfolio each day to a separate sheet. The script should be finding the next empty row and putting the current date in the first column and the value in the 2nd column. What it's doing is overwriting the row each time the script is run.

Here is my script:

```
function storePerf() {

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()["0"]);
  var source = ss.getRange ("Performance!G28");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Performance Historical");
  var numRows = source.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = source.getNumColumns();
  var nextColumn = numColumns +1;

  // Determine the first empty row to paste to.
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,2);

  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

  // Print date in the cell to the right of the latest price
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(),1).setValue(new Date());


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add the +1. Or add the flush function before. The script is faster then the added row.

SpreadshertApp.flush()
   destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(),1).setValue(new Date());

But then Isuggest you use appendRow and make it a lot easier:

```
var source = ss.getRange ("Performance!G28");
var destSheet =     ss.getSheetByName("Performance Historical");


//make a new row

var newRow = [source.getValue(), new Date()]

destSheet.appendRow([newRow]);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still having issues. I've tried what you suggested but I'm only getting the date to print in the left cell with no data in the right cell. It's appending a new row though so that's working. There was also a typo in one of my comments. I want the date on the left (column A) and source data on the right (column B), I also tried adding the flush function like you had but I got the same result. I should also add, when I formatted the 'var newRow' function like you had, I get this [Ljava.lang.Object;@6d6b7b87. I replaced the [ ]'s with ( )'s and that worked.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your sheet / script or a copy of it?